# HTML & DOM: How can an element or node be inserted at an arbitrary position within a text?

Tags: html, dom, text, insert

It would be possible to find the nearest element, and then replace it's inner HTML, but there has to be a DOM way.

( e.g. mouseclicking on a text will call a function that inserts an element at the text's position, pointed to by the mouse cursor.)

Is there some indexOf-like DOM function?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on ranges.

- [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM%3arange)
- [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28VS.85%29.aspx)

You'll probably want to get an empty range at a given point in your text and use [`.insertNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.insertNode) or [`.pasteHTML()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536656%28VS.85%29.aspx).

**Edit:** I tested this in Chrome and IE.  Onclick sets the selection to an empty range where you clicked:

```
document.onclick = function(e)
{
    if (window.getSelection)
    {
        getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode("x"));
    }
    else if (document.selection)
    {
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML("x");
    }
}
```

You may want to check the lenth of the selection and collapse the range if necessary to avoid overwriting the selected text.

Comment: Happy to help.  I added a better example to my answer.  Please make sure to go through each of your questions and accept and upvote the best answer (and upvote all the helpful answers) - you haven't accepted any answers yet.